# ajax is not accessing to my button inside datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables, jquery-ajaxq

I want to access to my button inside datatable which is inside of my modal, but when I want to access it wont load any alert , ajax url or whatever thing even If I change id or class of "a" tag. how can I fix it? this ajax I know it wont load and error in console, but it also show it..

ajax

```
    $(function(event) {
  URL_GET_VIEW_SEARCH_PRODUCT = BASE_URL + 'sale/sales/getViewSearch';
  URL_GET_DATATABLE = BASE_URL + 'sale/sales/datatable';
  URL_SEARCH_PRODUCT = BASE_URL + 'sale/sales/search_product';
  $('#btn-search').click(function (e) {
     BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Search Product',
        message: function(dialog) {
           var $message = $('<div></div>');
           var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
           $message.load(pageToLoad);
           return $message;
        },
        data: {
           pageToLoad: URL_GET_VIEW_SEARCH_PRODUCT
        },
        onshown: function(dialog){
           $('#example').DataTable({
                lengthChange: false,
                responsive: true,
                ajax: {
                  url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
                  type: 'POST',
                },
                columnDefs: [{
                targets: 4,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: "<a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a>"
              }],
           });
        }
     });
  });
   $('#search').typeahead({
      source: function (query,process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL_SEARCH_PRODUCT,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {query: query},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              process(data);
            }
        });
      }
   });

  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
        dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
        data: {param1: 'value1'},
      })
   });
});
```

table view

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: If it is not firing event that way then add `onclick` in your `a` like so `'<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>"` and call your `ajax` in `myFunction()`.

Comment: what is the diference? anon vs using functions? security ? the user can modify the fuction?

Comment: Even though, user can modify `$('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function(event) {}` by seeing into inspect and can get data from your `ajax url`..

Comment: If you want to stick this approach then lets have another try. Just add a class in your `'<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" class="myClickEvent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>"` and fire an event as follow `$('body').on('click', '.myClickEvent', function(e) {}`.

Comment: it's working, by now ,)